# How to animate swapping grid positions in css3?

Tags: css

I was looking at https://stackexchange.com/sites where clicking on an image swaps with another seemingly random image, and it looks like a really cool effect, and was trying to figure out how it was implemented - is it some sort of plugin? Also not sure if there is a proper name for this effect - if so, what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using a jquery plugin called isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 1):

for similar effects  `http://stackexchange.com/sites`

you can find from here: `http://packery.metafizzy.co/`